# Thomas precession and the whether or not the two frame can be directly boosted in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, precession

In the common treatment of the Thomas precession, there are three frames:

1. the rest frame of the nucleus
2. the instantaneous frame associated with the electron at the time t, having a velocity of v in the x direction.
3. the instantaneous frame associated with the electron at the time $t+\delta t$, having a velocity of v in the x direction (since the acceleration is perpendicular to the velocity), and a velocity of $0+a_{y}*\delta t$ in the y direction.

the frame 3 have a velocity $0\hat{x}+a_{y}*\delta t\hat{y}$ relative to frame 2, and a Lorentz boost from frame 1 to frame 3 can be written as :
\begin{equation}\exp\left(\frac{a_y}{c} \,\delta t\, K_y \right) \exp\left(\frac{v_x}{c}\,K_x\right) = \exp\left(\frac{v_x}{c}\,K_x  + \frac{a_y}{c}\,\delta t\, K_y + \frac{a_y\,v_x}{2\,c^2}\,[K_y,\,K_x]\,\delta t + \cdots\right)\tag{1}\end{equation}
the term $\frac{a_y\,v_x}{2\,c^2}\,[K_y,\,K_x]\,\delta t$ can be decomposed to a pure rotation and a pure boost, and that rotation is the source of the Thomas precession.

I wonder why just using a single boost \begin{equation}\exp\left(\frac{v_x}{c}\,K_x  + \frac{a_y}{c}\,\delta t\, K_y\right)\end{equation} to boost from frame1 to frame3 won't led us to the correct answer.

I want to know the difference in the physical meaning between "boost from frame1 to frame3" and "boost from 1 to 2, then from 2 to 3".

Comment: This is yet another example of a question whereby you need to tell us what kind of answer you would accept. Like, we could simply say that "If you just used one boost, obviously you will fail to derive the Thomas precession." Isn't it kinda obvious that we only really can trust the centre-of-mass frame, which we will take as if we are observing from there, and then it is necessary to compare the 2 individually and independently boosted frames? So, again, what is it you want in the answer?

Comment: OK, I've  edited

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking for physical intuition I think.

Part of the answer is to note that although we often use the phrase "the instantaneous rest frame" strictly this is ambiguous because for any given particle there are an infinite number of instantaneous rest frames, related to one another by rotations. So your "frames 1,2,3" should read something like:

1. a rest frame F1 of the nucleus
2. that instantaneous rest frame of the electron at the time $t$
   which can be obtained by a boost from F1, where $t$ is taken such that the relative velocity is in the $x$ direction. Call this frame F2.
3. that instantaneous rest frame of with the electron at the time $t+\delta t$, which can be obtained by a boost from F2. Call this frame F3.

For physical intuition, you can note various things. One good idea is to learn about the aeroplane flying around a polygon. The polygon is a large flat regular polygon of $N$ sides lying on the ground. An aeroplane flies above it. The pilot of the aeroplane finds the side ahead of it Lorentz-contracted so must steer through more than $2\pi/N$ (where $N$ is the number of sides) in order to follow a path above the regular polygon. Thus after completing a circuit the aeroplane has opened up an angle of more than $2\pi$ between itself and any object it carried with it and subjected to only boosts not rotations.

Another idea is the following. Since we have motion in a plane, it can be tracked using a three-dimensional spacetime diagram. The various inertial frames have planes of simultaneity sloping in various ways in such a diagram. Imagine the world-tube of something like a square frame whose centre follows the worldline of the electron, or else you could just use the worldtube of an object shaped like an arrow. The idea is that the motion is such that the cross-section of the world-tube of such a square or arrow in the plane of simultaneity of F2 has its sides parallel to those of the cross-section in the plane of simultaneity of F1. Also the cross-section in F3 is parallel to that in F2. One then finds that, owing to the way these planes are sloping, there is unavoidably a rotation between the cross-section in F3 and that in F1.

Finally, for a mathematical insight you can look at the geometry of the surface formed by all velocity 4-vectors. It is a hyperboloid. Boosts correspond to parallel transport on this surface. The surface is not flat so parallel transport can result in a net rotation.

For a proof of all the above you can try a book (e.g. the one I wrote).